# How should I use mock for certain case?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

Suppose that there are classes like:

**CivilAddSystem class :**

```
class CivilAddSystem{

    List<People> people = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Town> towns = new ArrayList<>();

    public People addPeople(People people) {
        people.add(people);
        return people;
    }

    public Town addTown(Town town) {
        towns.add(town);
        return town;
    }

    public House addHouse (House house, String townName) throws IllegalStateException {
        
        Town town = getTown(townName);
        if (null == town) throw new IllegalStateException("No matching town");

        town.addHouse(house);
        return house;
    }

public List<String> getTown(String name) {

        for (Town town : towns) {
            if (town.getName().equals(name)) return town;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Town class:**

```
public class Town {
    List<House> houses = new ArrayList<>();

    String name;
    String abbreviation;

    public Town (String name, String abbreviation) {
      
        this.name = name;
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }
    
    public void addHouse(House house) {
        houses.add(house);
    }
    
    public House getHouse(String unitNumber) {
        for (House house : houses) {
            if (house.getUnitNumber().equals(unitNumber)) return house;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**House class**

```
public class House {
    private final List<People> people = new ArrayList<>();

    private final String unitNumber;
    private final String houseName;

    public House (String unitNumber, String houseName) {

        this.unitNumber= unitNumber;
        this.houseName= houseName;
    }

    public String getUnitNumber() {
        return unitNumber;
    }

    public String getHouseName() {
        return houseName;
    }

    private People checkMovedInPeople(People person) {
        if (null == person) throw new NullPointerException();

        for (People movedIn : people) {
            if (movedIn.getName().equals(person.getName())) return movedIn;
            if (movedIn.getPersonID().equals(person.getPersonID())) return movedIn;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void moveInPeople(People person) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException {
         if (null == person) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Person shouldn't be null");
         if (null != checkMovedInPeople(person)) throw new IllegalStateException("Person is already in the house");

         people.add(person);
    }

    public List<String> getPeople() {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (People person: people) {
            results.add(person.getPersonID());
        }

        return results;
    }

    public People getPerson(String match) {
        for (People person: people) {
            if (person.getPersonID().equals(match)) return person;
            if (person.getName().equals(match)) return person;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And for the **people class**, it just has two variables: String PersonID and String Name and their getter methods.

So, what I want to achieve is that, I am currently trying to test the addPeople method in CivilAddSystem class and I want to test it independently using mockito.

The test case I wrote using JUnit is like this:

```
@Test
    public void testAddPeople() {
        CivilAddSystem CAS = new CivilAddSystem();
        Town town = CAS.addTown("BlueTown", "BT");
        House house = CAS.addHouse("U180", "BlueHouse", "BlueTown");
        People bob = CAS.addPeople("1", "Bob");
        Assert.assertEquals(CAS.getTown("BlueTown").getHouse("U180").getPerson("1"), null);

        house.moveInPeople(bob);
        Assert.assertEquals(CAS.getTown("BlueTown").getHouse("U180").getPerson("1").getPersonID, 1);
    }
```

But I am really struggling with applying mockito for this test case.

What I did so far is just mocking Town, House and People classes, (not the CivilAddSystem class since it is the one that is being tested), and stopped there...

Can anyone gives me a hint on how to apply mockito for that above test case?

p.s) A little bit of modification for the codes above is accepted (for example, applying dependency injection and something like this are accepted).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that you're testing `hose.moveInPeople` method instead of `CAS.addPeople` ...